# CSS hover animation for entire paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope someone might have an idea how to implement the following effect, without having to wrap separate lines into any inner elements such as span or a.

https://codepen.io/akronberg/pen/jaYdPJ

```
<div class="m-linkitem">
    <h1>Hover Below</h1>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor </a><br/>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><br />
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><br />
</div>


    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #111, #00393c);
        background-size: 400% 400%;
        animation: backgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #fff;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        line-height: 26px;
    }

    .m-linkitem {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        transform-origin: center;
        animation: loadBounce 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
    }

        .m-linkitem a {
            transition: all 0.25s linear;
            display: inline;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-size: 2.2rem;
            line-height: 45px;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 209, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(39, 143, 198, 1) 98%);
            background-size: 0px 2px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left 85%;
            text-shadow: 0;
        }

            .m-linkitem:hover a{
                background-size: 100% 1px;
                text-shadow: 0 2.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }
```

This will be implemented for responsive design so number of words per line would be changing on resize and point break changes.  Anyone can think of CSS way of underlining all lines simultaneously, like in the codepen example?

Thank you.

P.S.  This is what animation would look like when applied to entire paragraph. Not what I'm looking for:

https://codepen.io/colinhorn/pen/YxYYMj?q=underline+animation&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: Could you post your current css please?

Comment: Whats wrong with the codepen. Your css already wraps all the elemtents in a div, it would be silly not to use it...

Comment: I don't think its possible with only css. You will need javascript

Comment: It is possible, However I have to know number of words per line.  Due to responsive nature of the site this will be used for, I would be forced to use JS to recalculate every line for every paragraph to re-wrap text lines in <span> on every resize event.  I'm trying to avoid it if possible

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to replicate the *animation* in that codepen? Without using child elements?  (If so, please include that code *in the question itself* and maybe rewrite the question to be clearer about what you're asking -- as it stands the question is pretty misleading, it looks like you're just asking how to trigger text-decoration:underline on hover.)

Comment: @DanielBeck that is correct. Since I do not know number of words per line at the render time, I would have to dynamically adjust wrappers per every resize event.  I'm trying not to if possible

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw entire code is in the codepen.io link above the snippet

Comment: No it's not possible with multiple elements and css only. The second codepen works because it's ONLY ONE element

Answer (score 0):

First add `class="m-linkitem"` to every line in your html. Then you can use `text-decoration` to do underline the text without worrying about responsive design:

```
.m-linkitem{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This uses the class `m-linkitem` so that it highlights the whole paragraph by just hovering on ne part of it. The text-decoration doesn't need you to put in a specific length and underlines the simultaneously size changing text automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have fixed number of words per line.  Otherwise of course this would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think its very unclear what is it you're actually trying to achieve here.

From what I understand you are tring to replicate the exact same visual effect in the codepen you provided but without having to seperate each line into different elements.

I don't think it's a question of "how do you..." and I think its a question of "can you do...".

You are probably going to need to resort to Javascript or something of the likes...

The following example will add an underline to each line of text but its very hacky and probably won't work with the "responsive" design you are looking for:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #111, #00393c);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: backgroundGradient 30s ease infinite;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.m-linkitem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: loadBounce 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.m-linkitem a {
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 209, 177, 1) 0%, rgba(39, 143, 198, 1) 98%);
  background-size: 0px 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 85%;
  text-shadow: 0;
}

.m-linkitem a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 45px #ffffff, 0px 90px #ffffff;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
.m-linkitem a:hover:after {
  width: 380px;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-linkitem">
  <h1>Hover Below</h1>
  <a href="#">
    Lorem ipsum dolor <br>
    Lorem ipsum <br>
    Lorem ipsum <br>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Before I start, I have only a basic HTML & CSS knowledge, but I think it should work when you make a class. (Like they do in the example, and then add the wanted underlining.) The effect applies on everything within the class then.

```css
classname{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Or if you want to have it like a fancy effect. Copy the code into the class.

Greetings.

Comment: This would cause for entire paragraph to be animated one word at a time.  I need all lines to be animated simultaneously like in my original example.